# Calculate Average between columns by comparing two rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the below table

```
BidID AppID AppStatus   StatusTime
    1   1   In Review   2019-01-02 12:00:00
    1   1   Approved    2019-01-02 13:00:00
    1   2   In Review   2019-01-04 13:00:00
    1   2   Approved    2019-01-04 14:00:00
    2   2   In Review   2019-01-07 15:00:00
    2   2   Approved    2019-01-07 17:00:00
    3   1   In Review   2019-01-09 13:00:00
    4   1   Approved    2019-01-09 13:00:00
```

What I am trying to do is first to calculate the average of statusTime minutes difference by the following logic

First group by the BidID and then by AppID and then calculate the time difference between the StatusTime between In Review and Approved AppStatus

```
eg
First Group BidID,Then group App ID
```

, Then First Check for In Review Status and Find the Next Approved status and then have to calculate min difference between the dates

```
BidID  AppID    AppStatus                                          BidAverage
1 ->   1,2  ->  For App ID 1(2019-01-02       1hour                  1.5
                15:48:42.000 - 2019-01-02 
                12:33:36.000)
                For App ID 2(2019-01-04       2hour
                10:33:12.000 - 2019-01-04 
                10:33:12.000)
2->    2  ->    For App ID 2(2019-01-04       1                       1
                10:33:12.000 - 2019-01-04 
                10:33:12.000)
3->     1->     No Calculation since no Approved           

4->     1->    No Calculation since no In Review before Approved

Final Average (1.5 + 1) / 2 = 1.25 for the table
```

The time difference excluding saturday I have already figured out [Time Dfference Exluding Weekend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55052777/how-to-get-hours-between-two-dates-in-sql-server) using [David's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1236090/david-faber) suggestion.

I am not sure how to check if AppStatus is first in In Review and then Approved and then only calculate the time difference and if there is no Approved like in BidID 3 then don't use that in the average calculation and then average it across the APPId and then the BidID

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can just use `min()` and `max()` for simplicity to get the times for the bid/app pairs.  The rest is just aggregation and more aggregation.

The processing you describe seems to be:

```
select avg(avg_bid_diff)
from (select bid, avg(diff*1.0) as avg_bid_diff
      from (select bid, appid,
                   datediff(second, min(starttime), max(statustime)) as diff
            from t
            where appstatus in ('In Review', 'Approved')
            group by bid, appid
            having count(*) = 2
           ) ba
      group by bid
     ) b;
```

This makes assumptions that are consistent with the provided data -- that the statuses don't have duplicates for the bid/app pairs an that approval is always after review.

Comment: Hi Gordon..Bid can have duplicate pairs of AppID and one of it can be just Approved and the other can be In Review and then Approved..I have to see that In Review is followed by Approved and then calculate the time period. So in this case for the App ID I will just use the second one which has both In Review and Approved and leave the first one.

Comment: @user1221989 . . . This logic only includes bid/appid pairs that have two records. so if a pair has only one record, it does not contribute to the average.

Comment: Super Awesome..Gordon I really want to thank you so much